# umbraco array loop through issue

Tags: c#, .net, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

i am using CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("promo") but the for each not loop thorugh

```
    @{

  var SiteLinks = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("promo");
    if (CurrentPage.HasValue("promo"))
    {
        var promoListValue = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("promo");

     foreach (var item in promoListValue)
            {
                <span>@item.alias </span>
            }


    }
}
```

i am receive an error but when i print the promoListValue its displaying like this

```
[ { "alias": "1", "content": "1", "img": "/media/1069/509253678.jpg" }, { "alias": "Slide 2", "content": "2", "img": "/media/1074/636609180.jpg" } ]
```

can someone help me on this :)

even i have created a Property Value Converter so finaly the code is like this

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.HomePage>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent;
@using Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@using System.Linq;


@{
  Layout = "Master1.cshtml";
}



@{

    if (CurrentPage.HasValue("promo"))
    {
        var promoListValue = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("promo");



    @* var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     string json =  serializer.Serialize(promoListValue);
      var testmodel  = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);


    foreach (var item in promoListValue)
            {
                <span>@item </span>
            }  

           @Html.Raw(json) 
            @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(json))

             @Html.Raw(testmodel)  *@

            var obj = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel>("promo");
            <span>@obj </span>


    } 



}



<div class="container _borderless landingpage">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4 p0"><a href="/news">
             @Html.Partial("NewsCarousel")
        <!-- Main nav ends -->
         </a></div>
         <div class="col-md-8 p0">
         <article class="testimonial-feed p0">

        </article>
        <div id="test3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@functions {



public class MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet
{
    [JsonProperty("alias")]
    public string alias { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("img")]
    public string img { get; set; }
}

public class MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel
{
    private List<MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet> _Items;

    public MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel()
    {
        _Items = new List<MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet>();
    }

    public MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel(List<MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet> list)
    {
        _Items = list;
    }

    public IEnumerator<MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _Items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Any()
    {
        return _Items.Any();
    }
}

public class MyLookAlikeArchetypeModelPropertyConverter : IPropertyValueConverter
{
    public object ConvertDataToSource(PublishedPropertyType propertyType, object source, bool preview)
    {
        return source;
    }

    public object ConvertSourceToObject(PublishedPropertyType propertyType, object source, bool preview)
    {
        try
        {
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet>>(source as string);
            return new MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel(list);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertSourceToXPath(PublishedPropertyType propertyType, object source, bool preview)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsConverter(PublishedPropertyType propertyType)
    {
        return propertyType.PropertyEditorAlias.Equals("My.Plugin.Package.Manifest.Alias");
    }
}
}
```

but `var obj = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel>("promo");`

obj is comming empty

Comment: Have you tried to move your code (all that is inside "@functions{" ) inside a proper .cs file and not inside a view?

Comment: hi @Eyescream , if i move inside .cs file do i have to specifyu the file name in the view ?

Comment: You have to compile the .cs file (if placed outside of App_Code folder) and then reference to the namespace of the classes via @using correct_namespace_here; in your view